# Drupal forbidden 403

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

hye. I'm currently having some problem with drupal. Everything that I want to update/save is forbidden such as new content and update system settings. This message will appeared

"Forbidden.
You don't have permission to access/on this server.
Additionally, a forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an errordocument to handle the request"

I'm taking over this website from previous worker. I will be grateful if there is someone willing to help me to trace the problem. Thanks

Comment: Check your File/Folder permissions

Comment: do you mean the file for coding? I do not have all the coding files. is there any way for me to retrieve the data by only using the website?

Answer (score 0):

You must access to the server and check the permissions files and folders. Youcan't solve this using the website.